# Can I set up structs to 'using' a type when given a type? ('explicit specialization of non-template struct')

Tags: c++, templates, struct, template-specialization

I have the following struct and there will be many of these with different 'input' and 'output' types.

```
#include <string>

template <>
struct Corresponding<const char*> {
    using CorrespondingT = std::string;
};
```

This causes the error:

```
explicit specialization of non-template struct
      'Corresponding'
        template <> struct Corresponding<const char*> { using Correspond...
```

This should be usable as `Corresponding<T>::CorrespondingT` where T, in this case, could be `const char*`, but could be other types as more are added, e.g.

```
template <>
struct Corresponding<int> {
    using CorrespondingT = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;
};
```

then

```
template <typename T> using GetCorresponding = typename Corresponding<T>::CorrespondingT;
```

Sources that led me to believe that this would work: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference.

There have been other questions with this same error, but they seem to be attempting different things, making them not relevant here.

I'm using gnu++2a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply forgot to declare the primary template.

```
#include <string>

// You need this
template <typename T>
struct Corresponding;

template <>
struct Corresponding<const char*> {
    using CorrespondingT = std::string;
};
```

Without it, as the error says, `Corresponding` is not a class template (or indeed *anything*), so cannot have specialisations defined for it.

Instead of looking up references on unrelated things such as `std::hash` and `std::remove_reference`, review the chapter in your C++ book about template specialisations.

Comment: Sadly, I have no such book, but the issue was that I didn't know it was called 'template specialisation', which makes it harder to find documentation.

Comment: @Doot You should get one.